# Mongoose CastError for NodeJS App running on AWS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-ec2, mongoose

Basically, I have some code on my Node server like this:

```
var blogId =  req.params.blogId;   
Blog.findById(blogId).exec(...)
```

I get this error:

`{"message":"Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"5767399a90bf3cc2828d2cd6\" at path \"_id\" for model \"Blog\"","name":"CastError","stringValue":"\"5767399a90bf3cc2828d2cd6\"","kind":"ObjectId","value":"5767399a90bf3cc2828d2cd6","path":"_id"}`

I only get this error on my EC2 instance and not when I run it locally on my computer.  As you can see, that is a correctly formed ObjectId string and I have verified that it exists in my MongoDB.

This worked correctly as recently as a couple of days ago.  It suddenly started giving that error and I haven't changed the code.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and convert it to an `ObjectId` just to be sure. And, hopefully it will solve your issue too.

**Try this:**

```
var blogId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.blogId);
Blog.findById(blogId).exec(...)
```

I guess, `mongoose` is already defined in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of node do you have on your EC2 instance?
Recently I caught such a bug and fixed it by updating node to version 6.

You don't have to convert a variable blogId to ObjectId type,
this code is ok:

```
var blogId =  req.params.blogId;   
Blog.findById(blogId).exec(...)
```